# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') using Autocomplete in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Autocomplete in Angular

```
<input type="text" matInput [ngModel]="chatList" [matAutocomplete]="autocopmlete" (focus)="filter('')" (ngModelChange)="filter($event)">
<mat-autocomplete  #autocopmlete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayName">
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredObject" [value]="item" (onSelectionChange)="selectUser(item)">
            {{ item.Name }} 
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

i have this filter function in my `.ts file`

```
filter(value = '') {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || typeof value === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    this.filteredObject = this.chatList.filter(
        a => ~a.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
  }
```

filter is working but when i load my page and put focus on search textfield then getting this error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'filter')

Comment: Look like `chatList` didn't assign with value. Should also include handling for such scenario.

Comment: @YongShun Can you please guide me to handle this error on page load

Comment: Either you can use a `if` statement to check whether `chatList` is `undefined` or `null` before call the `.filter()`. Or you can look for optional chaining (`?.`). Not sure how you assign the value to `chatList`, but probably the mentioned approaches may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in chatList, you can add a condition to solve that:

```
filter(value = '') {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || typeof value === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    this.filteredObject = (this.chatList || []).filter(
        a => ~a.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
  }
```